# Mongo find - replace ObjectId with attribute of object when find

Tags: mongodb

Let say I obtain a find result as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5221517ad1b328371c000003"), "user_id" : ObjectId("5221517ad1b328371c000001"), "item_id" : ObjectId("5221517ad1b328371c000002"), "preference" : 22 }
```

The ObjectId is not quite meaningful. Is there a way to replace the ObjectId with an object's attribute? eg. for user_id -> change to username?

Comment: this result looks like it's structured in a relational way, meaning user_id is storing the objectid that can be found in another collection? is my assumption correct?

Comment: yes, your assumption is correct

Comment: @Karan you should read again about why people use Document-Oriented-Databases. You will not get any benefits if you will continue to use relation way of designing how you store data in Database.

Comment: @outcoldman - I understand, however, the reason my schema structure seems a bit relational is because I am using a library that requires this (http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/mongodb/MongoDBDataModel.html)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to use ObjectId as a data type for _id field. You can use set _id explicitly using any data type for example string:

```
> db.users.insert({_id: 'johndoe', age: 21}) 
> db.users.insert({_id: 'janedoe', age: 27})
> db.users.find({_id: 'janedoe'})

{ "_id" : "janedoe", "age" : 27 }
```

or integer

> db.items.insert({_id: 1, name: 'someitem'})

```
> db.items.find()

{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "someitem" }
```

as long as you can guarantee it has unique value:

> db.users.insert({_id: 'janedoe', age: 26})

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.users.$_id_  dup key: { : "janedoe" }
```

For the other hand ObjectID is meaningful, and can be used to obtain document creation time:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/